# Retrieve ArrayList value from GridView at BaseAdapter

Tags: java, android, gridview, arraylist

I have multiple arrays. And i sent it to GridView. So this is the example :

- Array A : 5,3,2,6
- Array B : Car, Knife, Laptop, Fan

I have two buttons. There is Plus and Minus.
So when  i press + / - buttons, automatically the value from Array A is changing. E.g i change the value of car (5) into (2), so the value from Array A become : 2,3,2,6

So the problem is i want to get that in ArrayList state again. Here is my code :

```
public class CustomGridView4 extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<ListItem> listData;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Context context;
    private int count = 0;
    private DBHelper myDb;
    public CustomGridView4(Context context, ArrayList<ListItem> listData) {
        this.listData = listData;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
        myDb = new DBHelper(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.afterlogin_product_gridview, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.headlineView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nama_produk);
            holder.teaserView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.harga);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_produk);
            holder.cmdMinus = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_min);
            holder.cmdPlus = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_plus);
            holder.qty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_qty);
            holder.layout1 = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout1);
            holder.satuan = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.satuan);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final ListItem newsItem = listData.get(position);
        String satuan = "/ " + newsItem.getSatuan().toString();
        String harga = newsItem.getReporterName().toString();
        Integer qtys = newsItem.getQuantity();
        holder.headlineView.setText(newsItem.getHeadline().toUpperCase());
        holder.teaserView.setText(harga);
        holder.satuan.setText(satuan);
        holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(qtys));
        String a = newsItem.getUrl();

        if (qtys == 0)
        {
            holder.layout1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_radius);
        }
        else
        {
            holder.layout1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_radius_gridview);
        }

        holder.cmdPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                count = newsItem.getQuantity();
                count++;
                newsItem.setQuantity(count);
                System.out.println("ASD : " + newsItem.getQuantity());
                holder.qty.setText("" + newsItem.getQuantity());
            }
        });

        holder.cmdMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                count = newsItem.getQuantity();
                if (count == 0) {
                    holder.qty.setText("0");
                    newsItem.setQuantity(0);
                } else {
                    count--;
                    newsItem.setQuantity(count);
                    holder.qty.setText("" +newsItem.getQuantity());
                }
            }
        });

        if (holder.imageView != null) {
            //new ImageDownloaderTask(holder.imageView).execute(newsItem.getUrl());
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(".BlanjaPasar/Product"), a);
            Picasso
                    .with(context)
                    .load(file)
                    .fit()
                    .noFade()
                    .into(holder.imageView);
        }

        holder.qty.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (!holder.qty.getText().toString().matches("0"))
                {
                    holder.layout1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_radius_gridview);
                }
                else
                {
                    holder.layout1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_radius);
                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView headlineView;
        TextView teaserView;
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView satuan,qty;
        Button cmdPlus,cmdMinus;
        LinearLayout layout1;
    }

}
```

The actions is in holder.cmdMinus & holder.cmdPlus buttons.

Here is the screenshot :

[image]

So when i press "Tambahkan" buttons, i want to get the arraylist value again. Is that possible ?

**Update :**

This is where ArrayList coming from my activity :

```
public ArrayList<ListItem> getListData() {
        ArrayList<ListItem> listMockData = new ArrayList<ListItem>();

        for (int i = 0; i < jArray; i++) {
            ListItem newsData = new ListItem();
            newsData.setKode(kode_prdct[i]);
            newsData.setUrl(img_prdct[i]);
            newsData.setHeadline(nama_prdct[i]);
            newsData.setReporterName(harga_prdct[i]);
            newsData.setSatuan(satuan_prdct[i]);
            newsData.setQuantity(qty_prdct[i]);
            listMockData.add(newsData);
        }
        return listMockData;
    }
```

And this is how i called the gridview :

```
 ArrayList<ListItem> listData = getListData();
        product_gridview.setAdapter(new CustomGridView4(AfterLogin_HistoryDetail.this, listData));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

**Method 1**

Making listData a class variable in the activity.

```
private ArrayList<ListItem> listData;
```

Because the listData is pass by reference, you are accessing the same copy.

```
listData = getListData();
product_gridview.setAdapter(new CustomGridView4(AfterLogin_HistoryDetail.this, listData));
```

**Method 2**

Expose it from adapter.

```
public class CustomGridView4 extends BaseAdapter {
    // Your code
    public ArrayList<ListItem> getListItems() {
        return listData;
    }
}
```

You also have to make the adapter a class variable.

```
private CustomGridView4 adpater;

ArrayList<ListItem> listData = getListData();
adpater = new CustomGridView4(AfterLogin_HistoryDetail.this, listData)
product_gridview.setAdapter(adpater);
```

Comment: If i use the method 1, how do i get the quantity value ? Am i needed to make a method similiar like getListData() again ?

Comment: @LeonardFebrianto Assume you know the position you want to get. `listData.get(i).getQuantity()` will work. If you use `getListData()` again, it will create a new list instead, which is not the one in the adapter.

Comment: Okay i get it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want retrieve the arraylist value in activity (out BaseAdapter) you can create a interface from Activity.

```
public interface OnChangeValueListener{
    void getValue(Object object);
}
```

In your activity implements this interface

```
MainActivity extends Activity implements OnChangeValueListener...

@Override
public void getValue(Object value){
  //get your value
}

public CustomGridView4(Context context, ArrayList<ListItem> listData, **YourListener**){
  this.onChangeValueListener = YourListener;
}

holder.cmdMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count = newsItem.getQuantity();
            if (count == 0) {
                holder.qty.setText("0");
                newsItem.setQuantity(0);

            } else {
                count--;
                newsItem.setQuantity(count);
                holder.qty.setText("" +newsItem.getQuantity());


            }

            **this.onChangeValueListener.getValue(value);**
        }
    });
```